# How to reuse new jsPDF() instance in generating multiple docs/pdfs from table rows?

Tags: javascript, api, jspdf, jspdf-autotable, caspio

Our backend is built-in Caspio, and in frontend we use use regular HTML, JavaScript, PHP. We've a table in our page with records, each consisting of a download button to generate pdf with data of that particular record fetched by calling an API. I've hardcoded here to make it look like client's sample docx, as there is no html to render for any record, instead of having reference of the record with ID. I used jsPDF before for such works, so used here too. It works well to generate the 1st PDF. But it can't create any more PDFs after the first one without loading the page.

If I try to download PDF more than once it shows "jsPDF pubSub.Error", which indicates that I couldn't create new jsPDF() instance multiple times on a single pageload as I'm not tied to the codebase or something like that..

## Sample Illustration of the table...

|  |  |  | Incident Report No | Date of Incident |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| View | Details | Download PDF Button | 100033 | 12/29/2022 |
| ... | ... | Download PDF Button | ... | .... |
| ... | ... | Download PDF Button | ... | .... |
| View | Details | Download PDF Button | 100027 | 12/23/2022 |

There are 2 scripts in our setup to make this happen. One is for fetching data for every record by calling an API, and the other is for generating the PDF. I'm sharing a glimpse of both.

## Fetch-Data Script

```
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");

// var callAddFont = function () {
//     doc.addFileToVFS('ArialUnicodeMS-normal.ttf', font);
//     doc.addFont('ArialUnicodeMS-normal.ttf', 'ArialUnicodeMS', 'normal');
// };
// jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont()]);


function getData(report_no) {
    showLoader();
    //console.log('Report No: '+report_no);
    $('#status').show();
    $("#preloader").show();

    $.ajax({
        url: "./script/callManagerReportData.php",
        type: "get",
        data: {
            report_no: report_no,
        },
        success: function (response) {
        
            let data = JSON.parse(response);
            let success = data.success;
            if(success == 0){
                alert(data.message);
            }else{
                let downloadpdf = HTMLtoPDF(window.jsPDF, doc, data);
                //console.log(downloadpdf);
                downloadpdf.then(value => {
                    //console.log(value);
                    if(value==1){
                        var element =  document.getElementById('dotsgif');
                        if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
                        {
                            element.innerHTML = 'Your download has completed.'
                        }
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }

            hidePreloader();

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        },
    });
}

function showLoader(){
    var loader = document.getElementById("status");
    loader.style.display = 'block';

}
function hidePreloader(){
    $("#status").delay(350).fadeOut("slow")
    $("#preloader").delay(350).fadeOut("slow")

}
```

> As you can see I've declared new jsPDF() at the top of the script, so that pdf-generate script can generate multiple PDF without the "pubSub.Error".

## PDF-Gennerate Script

```
async function HTMLtoPDF(windowjsPDF, doc, data) {
    console.log(data);

    var callAddFont = function () {
        doc.addFileToVFS('ArialUnicodeMS-normal.ttf', font);
        doc.addFont('ArialUnicodeMS-normal.ttf', 'ArialUnicodeMS', 'normal');
    };
    windowjsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont()]);
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    doc.save("My PDF.pdf");

    // for (var member in doc) doc[member] = '';

    // console.log(doc);

    var defaultTypeValues = {
        number: 0,
        string: '',
        boolean: false
    };

    function emptyObj(obj, defaultOverrides = {}) {
        var defaults = Object.assign({}, defaultTypeValues, defaultOverrides);
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = defaults[typeof obj[k]]);
        return obj;
    }

    console.log(emptyObj(doc)); 
}
```

> As you can see I'm trying to reinitialize the doc(->jsPDF()) object, but it seems to make the object properties undefined. So when I try to download the 2nd PDF, it throws error saying, "TypeError: doc.addFileToVFS is not a function", which is indeed a function of the jsPDF library.

I've tried different approaches like:

- reinitialize `doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4")`, or
- set empty `for (var member in doc) doc[member] = '';`
  at the bottom of pdf-generate script. Neither worked. Reinitialization do generate 2nd/3rd PDF with the previously(1st/2nd) generated PDF's data overlapped from the last page of the first one and in the console the "pubSub.Error" persists.

Comment: Where are you creating your `doc` and how are you calling your `HTMLtoPDF` function?
My guess is that you're creating a single `doc` for all the files, when you instead should probably call `let doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4")` inside your `HTMLtoPDF` function.

Comment: @LucasP.Luiz Thanks for thinking about the problem. At first, I did put `let doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4")` inside your HTMLtoPDF function. That works only for generating one pdf per pageload, it cannot generate multiple pdf on a single pageload. As you can see from the illustration I've multiple records in my table, each consisting of a PDF generate button. What I want is that once the page is loaded, the user can generate PDF for one or more records as per his requirement.